# как работать с loader при повороте экрана

Tags: java, android, android-loader

Не могу разобраться как организовать сохранение  при повороте экрана. Получаю информацию Json.

```
public class FragmentWeatherTestApplication extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<WeatherItem>> {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this).forceLoad();
}

 ...

@Override
public Loader<List<WeatherItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
    return new FetchWeatherLoader(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<WeatherItem>> loader, List<WeatherItem> data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished");
    mItems = data;
    setupAdapter();
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<WeatherItem>> loader) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
}

   .... 


  private static class FetchWeatherLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<WeatherItem>>{

    public FetchWeatherLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public List<WeatherItem> loadInBackground() {
        return new OpenWeatherFetch().fetchItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не описали, в чем именно ваша проблема. Loader не должен терять данные при повороте экрана.

Comment: каждый раз при повороте экрана выполняется загрузка данных, так вот не разберусь как этого избежать и загрузить уже полученые  до того данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forceLoad() — «принудительная» загрузка новых данных, а вы вызываете этот метод в onCreate, а значит при каждом повороте экрана. Вызывайте forceLoad в переопределенном методе "onStartLoading"

```
    private static class FetchWeatherLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {



    public FetchWeatherLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public List<WeatherItem> loadInBackground() {
        return new OpenWeatherFetch().fetchItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: без forseLoad не грузит вообще и не вызывает onLoadFinished, срабатывает только onCreateLoader

Comment: исправил, проверил, работает.